# OpenMP declare simd functions and pointer / ref arguments

Tags: c++, c, openmp, vectorization, simd

I need to vectorize a C++ function, which produces many (say 4) results. The caller uses those results in local calculations. Assuming I use `simdlen(4)` I need small constant space for 16 `double` numbers, or 4 vectors, each with 4 elements. I do not want to store those numbers in a large global array. Say an example function looks like this:

```
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4) linear(out:4)
void multifun(double v1, double v2, double *out)
{
  out[0] = (v1+v2)/2;
  out[1] = (v1-v2)/2;
  out[2] = (v1+v2)/3;
  out[3] = (v1-v2)/3;
}
```

**Question**: Is it possible to call this vectorized function with `out` being some *small* local/static variable? The below doesn't work, i.e., the call to `multifun` is not vectorized

```
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4)
double test1(double v1, double v2)
{
  double out[4];
  multifun(v1, v2, out);
  return out[0] + out[1] + out[2] + out[3];
}
```

That's reasonable - I need to provide more space for `out` and tell the compiler that it can use it in vectorized code. How do I do that?

What works is using a large generic array, which can be allocated and passed by the caller, and used as a temporary workspace, e.g.,

```
#pragma omp declare simd simdlen(4) linear(out:4)
double test2(double v1, double v2, *out)
{
  multifun(v1, v2, out);
  return out[0] + out[1] + out[2] + out[3];
}
```

But this is exactly what I want to avoid: the caller should not be bothered with the internals of the implementation and forced to provide (large) temporary storage.

Ideally, I would like to call `test1` from a `simd` loop similar to this:

```
void test_multifun(int n, const double *v1, const double *v2, double * result)
{

// should vectorize call to test1 - how??
#pragma omp for simd
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    result[i] = test1(v1[i], v2[i]);
  }
}

// this works, but requires O(n) temporary storage
#pragma omp for simd
  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    result[i] = test2(v1[i], v2[i], out+i*4);
  }
}
```

Is there a solution in the current OpenMP framework?

Comment: **What compiler are you using?**  Some (like gcc) are not good at auto-vectorizing for small (potentially unaligned) blocks of data.  Needing a broadcast before and a horizontal sum after makes vectorization less profitable for such a small problem.  I assume you compiled for x86 with SSE3 or higher, so ADDSUBPD was available?  Actually, `out[]` can be optimized away entirely by the compiler, so it doesn't need to have the elements in the right order for anything, so it can use `ADDPD` and `SUBPD` and multiply by a vector of `[1/2,  1/3]` (or divide if you didn't use `-ffast-math`)..

Comment: `test1()` can really optimize away a LOT of stuff down to something that doesn't look much like the source, if you enable `-ffast-math`.  I assume you're not doing that, but even still...

Comment: @PeterCordes That's just an example. Im using GCC and Intel ICC, and I do look at the generated asm - this is how I know if the function call is vectorized. I also prevent inlining to make sure there is an actual function call. What I'm after is how to call such vectorized functions. Real code is more computationally heavy of course. I understand that horizontal sum is not ideal, but considering that I'm doing 50 `exp` calls before the cost is not very large ;)

Comment: My point is that vectorization might not even be profitable on real hardware, as well as gcc's cost model.  And that clang is much better than gcc at vectorizing tiny stuff that amounts to one or two vectors, instead of a whole loop, in my experience.  gcc really wants to align pointers to the vector width, and doing that for only 4 `double`s isn't worth it.  (Although gcc's OpenMP auto-vectorization is different, and will usually use unaligned loads; presumably you're meant to run it on aligned data whenever possible if you're using OpenMP.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Vectorization is quite profitable in my case, and surprisingly GCC does better than ICC because of it's `exp` implementation. But again, it's not about speeding up this particular (useless) code - it's about how to (if possible) write an OpenMP `simd` function that returns many 'temporary' values, whether through a reference, or a pointer. Does OpenMP standard allow it somehow? or is it simply not available in the current version.

Comment: I see.  I think the key difference from the compiler's perspective is that test2 has side-effects on memory it doesn't "own".  `test1` can optimize away `out[]` entirely because it's a local, so I think it's not a matter of the *size*, it's that `test2` isn't allowed to optimize away the stores of the "vector" values into it.  (gcc doesn't know that  `p = malloc; p[0] = 1; free(p)` is a dead store, so even after inlining, dynamic allocation is the key difference, not just size.  I'm guessing you found that a `double out[4]` passed as an arg didn't work, but a malloced array did?)

Comment: gcc7.3 makes some vectorized versions of `test1` (https://godbolt.org/g/3xciSL), I guess so OpenMP callers can call it in various different ways, e.g. with vectors of `v1` and `v2` values.  In some of these, like `_ZGVcN4vv__Z5test1dd`, the `out[]` array has optimized away completely, and it's just AVX 256-bit vector ops.  Clang isn't OpenMP-aware, but still does some auto-vectorization on the scalar version of the function.  (Or with `-ffast-math`, turns it into one scalar add and FMA; like I was saying it's not the best test-case.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Very nice tool! didn't know about it. What I mean is more in these lines (https://godbolt.org/g/iMg2pa). The call to `test2` is vectorized in the `caller` function. But notice that when I call `test2` I must pass the last argument `temp+i*4`, which forces me to allocate a large (O(n)) array for what actually requires 16 doubles.

Comment: Is it really necessary for your real use-case to make these functions `noinline`?  Especially `multifun` itself.  That forces them to actually store / reload into that tmp array.  And although `_ZGVdN4vvl32__Z8multifunddPd:` is vectorized, it's probably worse than scalar on Intel CPUs, given all that shuffling.  I guess it's producing 4 vectors of 4 `double`s per call, but it's using 24 shuffle instructions for those 4 vectors.  That's horrible; at that point you should *definitely* just manually vectorize, maybe with `vfmaddsubpd` or whatever the intrinsic is called.

Comment: Anyway, if you remove the noinline from `multifun` (but not `test1`) then `test1` auto-vectorizes very cleanly with gcc.  https://godbolt.org/g/f2ErmR.  (And note that `__attribute__((noinline))` works on function definitions without a separate prototype if you put it *before* the function name.)  Also, you should definitely use `-march=haswell` instead of just `-mavx2`, because haswell *tuning* includes `-mno-avx256-split-unaligned-loads`.  (Your link had `vmovupd` / `vinserf128` split loads because gcc's generic tuning weights Sandybridge and some AMD CPUs very heavily for that.)

Comment: i.e. my guess is that gcc simply decides that auto-vectorization isn't profitable if it doesn't need to store the vector results to a permanent array as an observable side-effect, because it doesn't know how to do a *good* job auto-vectorizing with the `noinline` functions.  I don't really know OpenMP, so maybe I'm missing something here.  If so, use a better example in your question that doesn't require `noinline` to hobble the compiler.